# Iterate through selected rows in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables and mark ids of my table with

```
<tr data-id='1'>
```

tags. I want to get the ids of selected rows. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var $issueID = $(my_table.rows('.selected').nodes()).data('id');  
$.each($issueID, function (value, index ) { 
   alert(value);     
});
```

If I want to do it for a single row it works fine if I use

```
row().node()
```

but I can't get it right for many rows.

Comment: What is `my_table`?

Comment: Can you make a sample in https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @lilezek my_table is generated with var my_table = $('#my_table').DataTable({... });

Comment: It would help to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is a fiddle to view an alert of the single row. I want to do the same for multiple selected rows http://jsfiddle.net/mike89/ebRXw/3485/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var selectedIds = [];
var my_table = $('#my_table').DataTable(); 

my_table.rows('.selected').every( function() {
 selectedIds.push(this.data().id);
});
```

As Mike mentioned in a comment, notice that a capital D which is used to initialise the DataTable here. $().DataTable() returns a DataTables API instance, while $().dataTable() will also initialise a DataTable, but returns a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

While searching for the same answer I came across this article. I modified the code in your question to find a working solution.

```
                var inactiveRecord = $(my_table.rows('.selected').nodes());
                $.each(inactiveRecord, function (idx, value) {
                    alert($(value).data('id'));
                });
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use a Class to do this in addition to your `data-id`.

**JQUERY**

```
$('.row').each( function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(value);
})
```

**HTML**

```
<tr class="row" data-id="1">
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row" data-id="2">
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row" data-id="3">
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

or without a Class you could just use

```
$('tr').each( function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(value);
})
```

I recommend adding a class to `tr` so you don't accidentally get it mixed up with other rows that may not need to be counted.